# C# : TestStack.White fails to capture object with SearchCriteria.ByAutomationID provided by Inspect.exe

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework, teststack

I am using TestStack.White for automating a test on an existing application.

I have received a particular AutomationID `"example_ID"` for an element using **Inspect.exe**, however when I am using
`var something = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("example_ID");`

it says that it failed to get an element with the given ID. Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Would you be able to add what all you've tried and/or the other search criteria you could use?

Comment: A screen shot of inspect.exe would be very useful for determining why it cant find the element.

Comment: is your element visible? not below something else or out of scope, right?

Comment: i have the same problem. Upon clicking on an "add" button, a popup menu bar shows up next to it, but i cannot capture and click on the menuitem inside

Answer (score 0):

Does your automation-code run with the same privileges as your Inspect.exe-Instance?
Maybe it has no access to the GUI you want to automate:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-allow-uiaccess-applications-to-prompt-for-elevation-without-using-the-secure-desktop
states:
"However, there might be times when an administrative user runs an application with elevated privilege based on UAC in Admin Approval Mode. Microsoft UI Automation cannot drive the UI graphics of elevated applications on the desktop without the ability to bypass the restrictions that UIPI implements."